# Java - resize component whenever jframe is resizing

Tags: java, jframe, size, screen

I'm trying to make a game. I'm testing on multiple computers and While i tested it I saw in a different computer which have a different screen that all the size of the components in the JFrame have changed.
How can I manage to re-size components when JFrame is re-sizing?

NOTE : I saw multiple threads about this subject and none of them fixed my issue.

EDIT: Let's put some code to begin with :

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        width = screenSize.getWidth();
        height = screenSize.getHeight();
        ImageIcon main_Icon = new ImageIcon(ICON);
        setName("NAME");
        setIconImage(main_Icon.getImage());
        setResizable(false);
        setUndecorated(true);


        character_Label= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ICON);

        character_Panel= new JPanel();
        character_Panel.add(character_Label);
        character_Panel.setOpaque(false);
        character_Panel.setSize(35, 35);
        character_Panel.setLocation((int) width / 2, 0);

        ImageIcon restart_Button_Icon = new ImageIcon(ICON);
        ImageIcon menu_Button_Icon = new ImageIcon(ICON);

        restart_Button = new JButton();
        restart_Button.setIcon(restart_Button_Icon);
        restart_Button.setSize(110, 45);
        restart_Button.setLocation((int) width / 2 - (restart_Button.getWidth() / 2), (int) height / 2 - 100);
        restart_Button.setVisible(false);
        restart_Button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        restart_Button.setFocusPainted(false);
        restart_Button.setOpaque(false);

        menu_Button = new JButton();
        menu_Button.setIcon(menu_Button_Icon);
        menu_Button.setSize(110, 45);
        menu_Button.setLocation((int) width / 2 - (menu_Button.getWidth() / 2), (int) (height / 2));
        menu_Button.setVisible(false);
        menu_Button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        menu_Button.setFocusPainted(false);
        menu_Button.setOpaque(false);

        Danger_1= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MainActivity.class.getResource(ICON);
        Danger_2= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MainActivity.class.getResource(ICON);
        Danger_3= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MainActivity.class.getResource(ICON);
        Danger_4= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MainActivity.class.getResource(ICON);
        Danger_5= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MainActivity.class.getResource(ICON);
        Danger_6= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MainActivity.class.getResource(ICON);

        Danger_1 = new JPanel();
        Danger_1.add(line_Label_1);
        Danger_1.setOpaque(false);
        Danger_1.setSize(300, 30);
        Danger_1.setLocation(0, 200);

    Danger_2 = new JPanel();
        Danger_2.add(line_Label_2);
        Danger_2.setOpaque(false);
        Danger_2.setSize(300, 30);
        Danger_2.setLocation((int) width - Danger_2.getWidth(), 300);

        Danger_3 = new JPanel();
        Danger_3.add(line_Label_3);
        Danger_3.setOpaque(false);
        Danger_3.setSize(300, 30);
        Danger_3.setLocation(0, 400);

        Danger_4 = new JPanel();
        Danger_4.add(line_Label_4);
    Danger_4.setOpaque(false);
        Danger_4.setSize(300, 30);
        Danger_4.setLocation((int) width - Danger_4.getWidth(), 500);

        Danger_5 = new JPanel();
        Danger_5.add(line_Label_5);
        Danger_5.setOpaque(false);
        Danger_5.setSize(300, 30);
        Danger_5.setLocation(0, 600);

        Danger_6 = new JPanel();
        Danger_6.add(line_Label_6);
        Danger_6.setOpaque(false);
    Danger_6.setSize(300, 30);
    Danger_6.setLocation((int) width - Danger_6.getWidth(), 700);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setSize((int) width, (int) height);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(restart_Button);
        add(menu_Button);
        add(character_Panel);
        add(Danger_Panel_1);
        add(Danger_Panel_2);
        add(Danger_Panel_3);
        add(Danger_Panel_4);
        add(Danger_Panel_5);
        add(Danger_Panel_6);
```

I'll explain a bit now.

The character panel is the main character which moves.
the danger_1 , danger_2 etc.. are the spikes in the ground.

Comment: What layout are you using for the JFrame?

Comment: without viewing ur code, no one can help u.Plz share ur code.

Comment: @prasanth , I'm using (null) , I'll edit the code , just a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your code you use the width and the height of the screen to set the size of the JFrame.

You should do the same thing, but proportionally, when you set the size of the character and the "dangers".

E.g. if the character should always be as high as 1/10 of the height of the frame and as wide as 1/10 of the width of the frame then you should do something like `character.setSize(width/10, height/10);`.